# Inheriting a field value based on a different one

Tags: sql, ms-access

There is table of people `tblPeople`, each have an ID field and a on vacation (yes/no value) field.

I have a form which inherits an ID of a person from a different form. Because both forms use a different table than `tblPeople`, that different table has only the person's ID field and not his vacation field, so I can't inherit the vacation field directly.

What I want is to get the vacation value for that person: I thought that I could create a combo box which has a record source: `SELECT Vacation FROM tblPeople WHERE tblPeople.ID = Me.txtID` which will return only 1 record, and then code it to automatically pick first value and keep it hidden or something. But that involves some pointless, clumsy, and ugly code.

My question is if there's an alternative method to doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base the form on a query that left joins in the vacation field. Then the field will display automatic and without code. And better is if the vacation value changes, then no update code etc. will be required – in fact this is the whole beauty of a relational database!